# ckeditor 4.6 issue with config.filebrowserBrowseUrl

Tags: ckeditor

I'm running the new version of ckeditor (4.6) on IIS (This ia a classic asp site not that it should matter).
The integration with ckfinder is fine. I can upload images, browse server, etc.. 
My only remaining issue is with the link function itslef: when I click 'browse' I keep being redirected to:
/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php?CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

My config.js file is

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.language = 'en';
config.height = '550px';
config.removeButtons = "Styles,Font,FontSize,Smiley,Flash";
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "[my-path-to-cms]/ckfinder/ckfinder.html"
```

etc..

My question is why the "browse" is loading the file "/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php" instead of the one setup in the config.js: /ckfinder/ckfinder.html?

And how can I make sure the correct file is being used?

There are tons of questions about this issue on the web, but it seems to version dependent and I couldn't find any satisfying answers.

Any tips / ideas would be really useful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use imageuploader plugin in your config file in `ckeditor/config.js` set

`config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'your custom path';`

for browse server working fine.

Comment: This is correct answer but stackoverflow down voted it, and I don't no why

Answer (score 0):

The browse is loading the file "/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php" because you have the imageuploader plugin install width your ckeditor.

You may have download a custom install of ckeditor including imageupload or perhaps have you add the plug in later and activate it into the config with 
config.extraPlugins = 'imageuploader'; in config.js.

If you don't want to use image uploader you have to download the standard version of ckEditor.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have imageuploader installed and don't want to install a new version of CKEditor you can remove the plugin in "config.js" like this.

```
config.removePlugins = 'imageuploader';
```

that way it should use what you have entered for config.filebrowserBrowseUrl